# Querying SimpleXML result in PHP

Tags: php, syntax, simplexml

I'm using SimpleXml in PHP and it works well for me.

Recently I had a problem when trying to grab a particular node (I hope that's the right term).

Here's a sample XML

```
<xml>
    <attribute>
        <item name="fun_level">
            <value>Really Fun</value>
        </item>
    </attribute>
</xml>
```

So I'm using simplexml to get all the attributes, and run them through a loop, which all works fine. However, when I want to grab the "value" for an item with a particular name, I'm having trouble.

This works if I'm just trying to grab the value for the first item:

```
$value = (string)$attribute->item[0]->value;
```

Unfortunately I want to refer to a specific item, so I'm trying to do something like this, which isn't working:

```
$value = (string)$attribute->item["@name='fun_level'"]->value;
```

I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong with my syntax where I refer to the name attribute of the item. Should I be using round brackets? braced? Do I need to do something different with the quotes?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I should mention, based on the first answer from A.Sterling, that I'm already using SimpleXML and xpath to pull out the attributes (there are many) and loop through them. This is a nested loop issue I'm working with here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) method.

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$xml = '<xml>
    <attribute>
        <item name="fun_level">
            <value>Really Fun</value>
        </item>
    </attribute>
</xml>';

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($sxe->xpath('//item[@name="fun_level"]') as $item){
    echo $item->value;
}
```

Also, see the manual page describing SimpleXML's [basic usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) for more examples.

Comment: I may have been confusing in my description. I'm already using SimpleXml to parse the XML and pull out the different attribute elements. I have a "foreach($sxe->attribute as $attribute)" that I'm already looping through (to use your sxe variable). It is not possible to do what I'm asking without using "xpath" again?